# innerHTML not showing up despite it being called

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

This bug is actually pissing me off lol so i want to make a quiz game and each question will be updated based on the objects inside the question variable and everything is working but num.innerHTML = `${ques.id}` and i do not know why

```js
let score = 0
let i = 0

const prev = document.querySelector("#prev")
const next = document.querySelector("#next")

const num = document.querySelector("#num")
const q = document.querySelector("#question")

const ans1 = document.querySelector("#ans1")
const ans2 = document.querySelector("#ans2")
const ans3 = document.querySelector("#ans3")
const ans4 = document.querySelector("#ans4")

const questions = [{
    id: 1,
    q: "What is the capital of Indonesia?",
    a1: "Jakarta",
    a2: "Bandung",
    a3: "Surabaya",
    a4: "Bali",
    c: "Jakarta"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    q: "Who won the 2017 NBA MVP Award?",
    a1: "Lebron James",
    a2: "Russell Westbrook",
    a3: "Kawhi Leonard",
    a4: "James Harden",
    c: "Russell Westbrook"
  }
]

function update(ques) {
  num.innerHTML = `${ques.id}`
  q.innerHTML = ques.q

  ans1.innerHTML = ques.a1
  ans2.innerHTML = ques.a2
  ans3.innerHTML = ques.a3
  ans4.innerHTML = ques.a4
}

update(questions[0])
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="question">
    <div id="num">1.</div>
    <div id="ques">What is 10 x 10</div>
  </div>
  <div id="answers">
    <div id="ans1" class="button">100</div>
    <div id="ans2" class="button">40</div>
    <div id="ans3" class="button">25</div>
    <div id="ans4" class="button">1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="toggle">
    <div id="prev">Prev</div>
    <div id="next">Next</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect the element content to be? Have you checked for errors in the console? When does `update()` run other than the initial call in the code you posted?

Comment: hi @Pointy i expect the num.innerHTML to show the number of the question and yes i already checked in the console and there were no errors yet it still isn't showing

Comment: OK so when and how is `update()` called? There's only one call in the code you posted, and it always updates to the first question.

Comment: yea i haven't progressed further to the code where i would call the next questions because I still want to figure out the issue for this current code before continuing. even when i call update for that 1 question only everything else is visible except for id for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#num` is contained in `#question`, and you are updating the whole `#question` innerHTML.

Solution, use `#ques`:

```js
const q = document.querySelector("#ques");
```